# Getting data from many different tables in SQL using EF is slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a form on a web page with several combo boxes, each combo box is listing entries from different tables in the same database.

when testing my code it seem slow for the web page to open because of all the data retrieved from SQL.

is there a more efficient way to retreive my combobox data?

here is the code I use to populate ther lists onGet later used in razorpages for populating comboboxes

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id) {

                List1 = await _dbcontext.tbl1.ToListAsync();
                List2 = await _dbcontext.tbl2.ToListAsync();
                List3 = await _dbcontext.tbl3.ToListAsync();
                List4 = await _dbcontext.tbl4.ToListAsync();
    }
```

Comment: you are converting whole table to list.. that means if your tables have 1000s of records that 1000s of records will be hold in memory of server that is why it may become slow... try optimizing your query and use tolist only for required rows and not whole table or use pagination

Comment: Not entirely sure what your requirements are but if this page needs to load fast i would consider caching these results as json and returning the json directly from the file or reddis

Answer (score 4):

This is kind of broad question. We need more information to provide you ideas. But I suggest you split the action into four different calls (AJAX calls) so the comboboxes will be loaded constantly.

Something like

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync1(int? id) 
{
    return await _dbcontext.tbl1.ToListAsync();
}
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync2(int? id) 
{
    return await _dbcontext.tbl2.ToListAsync();
}
...
```